# How to remove a key from a 2 dimensional dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to use `pop` to remove a key from a 2 dimensional dictionary. I keep thinking that `forward_hash[first_key].pop(second_key)` should work but it's not.

Comment: As an aside, you can use tuples as dictionary keys: forward_hash[ first_key, second_key ] = blah.

Answer (score 4):

It appears to work for me:

```
>>> forward_hash = {"first_key": {"second_key": "data"}}
>>> forward_hash["first_key"].pop("second_key")
'data'
>>> forward_hash
{'first_key': {}}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to remove `second_key` from all of your dicts, you should do:

```
forward_hash = dict( a=dict(...), b=dict(...), ...)
second_key = "blah"
for d in forward_hash.itervalues():
    d.pop(second_key)
```

Comment: Only you actually managed to see what might be the real problem here. Nice one.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you intended to use pop(). Usually to delete a key from a dictionary I would use the `del` operator:

```
>>> forward_hash = {"first_key": {"second_key": "data"}}
>>> del forward_hash["first_key"]["second_key"]
>>> forward_hash
{'first_key': {}}
```

See [this article](http://diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/dictionaries.html#odbchelper.dict.del) for more details and other info on using dicts.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work just fine for me:

```
>>> d = {'a': {'b': 'c'}}
>>>
>>> d
{'a': {'b': 'c'}}
>>> d['a']
{'b': 'c'}
>>> d['a'].pop('b')
'c'
>>> d['a']
{}
>>>
```